# how do I wrap a program with a parent process so that I can restart in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, child-process, restart

I've got an application on a [Replit REPL](https://replit.com/@Perodactyl/Omnitex-Hacking-Sim#index.js) and can't get it to restart. If you open the shell tab and run `node start.js` than it makes a `childProcess` to wrap the main thing. This is mostly to be able to restart by running `process.send("rs")`. All code is visible and editable from the link. Can I get help?

Comment: Did you contact repl.it support already? Because as a paid service (even if it lets you use it in some capacity for free) that's the first place to ask.

Comment: No. I haven't thought of asking on the website. I'll try that!

Comment: Ok, I've asked.

Comment: I've had no luck. I need help from stackoverflow.

Comment: A suggestion: don't use processes. Give your node server a special admin-only shutdown command, and then run your node task using `pm2` or `nodemon` (both of which can be told to autorestart on exit, so you tell node to exit, it exits, pm2/nodemon restarts it - same effect, no complicated thread/process gimmicks).

Comment: @Mike This is on replit, I don't know how to change how it starts. And then, the actual thing running wouldn't be able to send a message to tell it to quit.